# call broadcast receiver being triggered three times

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, retrofit2, android-room

```
public class callLogs extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String phNumber, callType, callDate, callDuration, dir;
    Date callDayTime;
    List<calls> data = new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    private callsData callsData;
    private callsDb callsDb;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "callsData";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = pref.edit();

    callsData = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
            callsData.class, DATABASE_NAME).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();

   // cd = new ConnectionDetector(context.getApplicationContext());

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(500 , 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }


            Cursor managedCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, strOrder);
            int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
            int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
            int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
            int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
            int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
            sb.append("Call Details :");

            managedCursor.moveToFirst();

           // while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {

                String pName = managedCursor.getString(name);
                phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number); // mobile number
                callType = managedCursor.getString(type); // call type
                callDate = managedCursor.getString(date); // call date
                callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
                callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
                dir = null;

                // Log.d("Name",pName);
                int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
                switch (dircode) {
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        dir = "OUTGOING";
                        break;

                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                        dir = "INCOMING";
                        break;

                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                        dir = "MISSED";
                        break;

                    case CallLog.Calls.REJECTED_TYPE:
                        dir = "REJECTED";
                        break;
                }

            new  Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callsDb = new callsDb();
                    callsDb.setPhone(phNumber);
                    callsDb.setType(dir);
                    callsDb.setDate(String.valueOf(callDayTime));
                    callsDb.setDuration(callDuration);
                    callsData.callsDao().insertAll(callsDb);
                }
            }).start();

                sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
                sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
           // }
            managedCursor.close();
            // textView.setText(sb);
            Log.d("Agile", sb.toString());
            Log.d("data",callsDb.getPhone());
            Log.d("type kya hai",callsDb.getType());

            calls person = new calls();
            person.setMobile(callsDb.getPhone());
            person.setType(callsDb.getType());
            person.setDate(callsDb.getDate());
            person.setDuration(callsDb.getDuration());
            data.add(person);

            Bean b = (Bean) context.getApplicationContext();

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(b.baseURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
            Allapi cr = retrofit.create(Allapi.class);

            callsBean body = new callsBean();

            body.setCallLogs(data);

            Gson gsonObj = new Gson();

            String jsonStr = gsonObj.toJson(body);

            String id = pref.getString("id", "");
            Log.d("id", id);
            Log.d("id", pref.getString("id", ""));
            Log.d("id", jsonStr);

            Call<callsBean> call = cr.calls(id, jsonStr);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<callsBean>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<callsBean> call, Response<callsBean> response) {

                    Log.d("response", response.body().getCallLogs().toString());

                    /*new  Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                    callsData.callsDao().delete(callsDb);
                        }
                    }).start();*/

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<callsBean> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
    };

    countDownTimer.start();
```

}

> I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` for call code is working fine and storing data in `Room` `Database`, latest call is being stored but there i am calling an Api to store data on server as well getting from `Room` `Databse`
>   but the problem is Api being hit three times i think because of broadcast 
>   receiver.
>   When call is incoming first api will hit on incoming the second on receiving time and third it will hit on end call time, this happening as well in missed call and outgoing call time.
>   please help me to find the solution for this.
>   i want Api should hit only one time

Comment: have you implemented phone call listener?

Comment: @ZaidMirza i didn't implemented, can you please help me to do so?

Comment: use a shared pref value with boolean isFirstCall, change value on first time when gets triggered broadcast for first time, then manipulate...btw don't use count down timer, use handler/alarm mgr/scheduler